# Oracle SQL Find First Match from single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that lists concurrent program IDs and names. However, the table allows more than one name for each program ID. I'm needing to report some data about the programs, but am having trouble getting it to display correctly, as the program name is what is being displayed and grouped by in Tableau.

So what I need is a way to pull the first name for each program ID from the table. Since I'm including the program name in my output, I can't use unique (it wouldn't filter the alternate names) & I can't use a join as there wouldn't be a unique match.

Comment: sample data and table structure please

Comment: And define "first".  A heap-organized table is inherently unordered so "first" and "last" are only meaningful in the presence of a specified sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options (of varying efficiency) to get the (alphabetically) first name for each id.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09ce9/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAMS ( ID, NAME ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'Charlie' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'Bob'     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'Alice'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Ed'      FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Doris'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Fern'    FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Godfrey' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       MIN( NAME ) AS NAME
FROM   PROGRAMS
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09ce9/3/0)**:

```
| ID |  NAME |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Doris |
|  3 |  Fern |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ID,
       FIRST_VALUE( NAME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL ) AS NAME
FROM   PROGRAMS
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09ce9/3/1)**:

```
| ID |  NAME |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Doris |
|  3 |  Fern |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME
FROM   PROGRAMS p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM   PROGRAMS x
                    WHERE  p.ID = x.ID
                    AND    p.NAME > x.NAME )
ORDER BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09ce9/3/2)**:

```
| ID |  NAME |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Doris |
|  3 |  Fern |
```

Comment: For the record I used option 1